Wrap picture around enumerate
I want to wrap a picture around this enumerate, but it keeps sending the picture to the end of the document when I try to use the wrapfigure environment. How can I do it?
This is the code, and I would like the picture on the right with the text wrapped around it:
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 10pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Activity 1} Activity instructions. 
\vspace*{0.15em}
\begin{enumerate}
\itemsep-0.2em
\item A sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img2.jpeg}
\end{figure} 

\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank. 
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
   
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}  


?? How do you want to wrap an image around some block which contains a list ?? Can you provide a mockup/sketch? // Why do you think a float (figure) can do that? Thank you

you are asking about wrapfig but your example does not use the package or environment of that name.   your float is using the optional argument to prevent it going at the top or bottom or on a page on its own so going to the end of the document is quite likely

Jhon Kormylo got it!

So long as you only break between paragraphs (items), not a problem.
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Activity 1} Activity instructions. 
\vspace*{0.15em}
\begin{enumerate}
\raggedright
\itemsep-0.2em
\item A sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.

\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr 0.7\textwidth-\columnsep}% left column
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn[1]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{figure} 
\switchcolumn
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank. 
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\end{paracol}
\item Another sentence with an underlined \underline{\hspace{5cm}} blank.
\end{enumerate} 

\end{document}

